# How to use CDATA in html documents?

Tags: html

What is wrong with my HTML document?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p><![CDATA[I can't see this text :(]]></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why don't I see the text inside `CDATA`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Explicit CDATA sections are, in practice, unsupported in `text/html` documents. They are marked as a feature authors should [avoid because they have limited support](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.5).

Your browser is probably treating it as an unknown element.

Comment: Do you know any alternative to `CDATA`? How can I use a potentially ill-formed XML/HTML inside well-formed XHTML document?

Comment: Alternative to CDATA? Replace characters with special meaning with entities. Dealing with ill-formed data? Clean it up before inserting it (maybe with an HTML 5 parser) or reject it if it isn't well-formed at the input stage.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the MIME type of the web page from `text/html` to `application/xml`. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @Vincenzo IE doesn't support `application/xml`.