# How to simulate xmp bahavior

Tags: html, xmp

I read that xmp tag is deprecated, but I need to output code as plain text. So is there some way how to simulate xmp tag behavior? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simulate the special parsing mode of `xmp` elements in HTML, except in genuine XHTML (i.e., XHTML served with an XML media type), where you can use [`CDATA` sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850804/why-is-the-cdata-section-in-my-html-not-rendering). The reason is that this is about low-level parsing of HTML, hard-wired into browsers.

So if you don’t want to use `xmp`, the only way is to “escape” the characters “&” and “<” in the content. Note that HTML5 drafts require browsers to keep supporting `xmp` (while declaring it as obsolete and forbidden).

Comment: Actually one can simulate legally `<xmp>` tag with `<script type="text/plain"></script>`, the only disadvantage is that firefox (ONLY) don't allow to copy content as described here: [Emulate XMP tag with script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55168390/1725210)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` or `<code>`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp):

> Use the **`<pre>`** element or, if semantically adequate, the **`<code>`** element
>   instead. Note that you will need to escape the '<' character as '<'
>   to make sure it is not interpreted as markup.

Comment: Could it be possible without escaping any characters?

Comment: @anagmate Yes, it possible using `<script type="text/plain"></script>` tag. Take a look on example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55168390/1725210)